# ASP.NET WebAPI returning Http 405

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-modules

I have a WebApi controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/invitations")]
public class InvitationsApiController : ApiController
```

And an action method:

```
[Route]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Create([FromBody] CreateCommand command)
```

When i try to POST to http://host/api/invitations i get a "“405 Method Not Allowed”

But when I use another route like:

```
[Route("test")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Create([FromBody] CreateCommand command)
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    SetupFormatters(config);

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi", 
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
}
```

And make a POST to http://host/api/invitations/test its working. I have controllers that works just perfect when requesting to "root".

More details on Http error:

> HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed The page you are looking for
>   cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being
>   used.

```
Detailed Error Information: 
Module    DefaultDocumentModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler  
Handler    StaticFile  Error
Code    0x80070001  
Requested URL   http://localhost:8008/api/invitations  
Physical Path <removed>   
Logon Method  Anonymous  
Logon User    Anonymous
```

Any suggestions what might be wrong?

Comment: do you have a route conflict? 2 methods decorated the same way?

Comment: Do you happen to have a physical/virtual directory in the `~/api/invitations` path? Otherwise, you'll have to show your `Web.Config`...

Comment: Remove the [Route] attribute from your method or change it to [Route("")]

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Ive just checked, no route dublicates.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov + HaukurHaf tried that as well, same result.

Comment: @haim770 I have a physical path ~/API\Invitations

Comment: You have a physical directory named `API` and another physical directory named `Invitations` in it? Why?

Comment: Can you post your startup code too? Are you, by any chance, also using convention based routing too?

Comment: Does calling `http://host/api/invitations/create` work? What happens when you annotate your action with `[ActionName("Post")]`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov System.Http.Net

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Its running on IIS,  sure i am sending a POST request.

Comment: @AnishPatel updated the question with route config.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov everything is running on localhost

Comment: Change `RoutePrefix` to `Route`: `[Route("api/invitations")]` at the controller level

Comment: delete `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi", 
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });`

Comment: @AnishPatel: Tried to remove the route, same result.

Comment: Updated question with http error details.

Comment: Have you looked at my answers suggestion?

Comment: The module returning the error is `DefaultDocumentModule` and the handler is `StaticFile`. It means that you really have a physical directory in `~/api/invitations`. What's in there?

Comment: @haim770  ~/API/Invitations contains InvitationsApiController.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're having a physical directory that is matching your route (`/api/invitations`). Because such physical directory exists, IIS native `DirectoryListingModule` and `DefaultDocumentModule` modules (that are not allowing the `POST` verb) are taking over the request before the `TransferRequestHandler` (that is used by MVC and WebAPI) is able to handle it.

There is no reason to put your `InvitationsController.cs` in the same directory stucture that is going to match the requested route. That's why we have routing in the first place, to be able to register routes dynamically regardless of the physical location of the controller.

The common convention (that is also the default WebAPI template structure) is to put your controllers in the `~/Controllers` directory (or `~/Controllers/Api`). But you can actually put them in any directory as long as they're getting compiled as part of the project.

Comment: That is working like a charm =) actually pretty obvious when explained. Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what was happening to me. I flattened the directory structure and it started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change your controller `RoutePrefix` declaration to `Route` at the controller level:

```
[Route("api/invitations")]
public class InvitationsApiController : ApiController
```

`RoutePrefix` doesn't add the route to the route table. This means, that if you want to use `RoutePrefix`, you'll have to prefix each action by itself, for example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/invitations")]
public class InvitationsApiController : ApiController

[Route("")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Create([FromBody] CreateCommand command)
```

Comment: Yes, but it has nothing to do with the error being returned

Comment: @haim770 Did you try [Route("")] instead of [Route]?